# VS 2015 Xamarin "@(Content) build action is not supported" but for a DLL

Tags: c#, android, dll, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Have warning message "@(Content) build action is not supported" for a DLL when building a Xamarin Android application with VS 2015. This DLL has same Properties as other DLLs in same project References but this is only one complaining. Found post mentioning the same error but for the Manifest but in my case is a DLL.

Any ideas?

Versions installed:
Xamarin 4.0.1.89 / 
Xamarin.Android 6.0.1.10

As can be seen, Manifest build action is none.

[image]

The DLL that causes the warning:

[image]

Comment: Can you point out that specific `.dll` ?

Comment: @Vaikesh added a screenshot of .dll Properties

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I had my emulator running for a different solution.

Not sure if this will work for you, but by **starting the emulator from the current solutio**n worked for me.